# Why images are rotated if we resize width using dropzone

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have a simple script to upload images using dropzone v5 , but when I use the option "resizeWidth", the images are uploaded but with **rotation** especially the photos taken by mobile phone I guess.
How we can prenvent that ?

```
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop",
        {
            paramName: "files",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            parallelUploads: 50,
            maxFilesize: 100, // MB
            acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpeg, .jpg, .gif",
            resizeWidth: 1000,
            resizeQuality: 0.8,
            url: "{{ path('property_upload_photos', {'token': property.token}) }}",
        });

    $("#add_file").on("click",function (){
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
```

Comment: It's been an hour, and although I don't have an answer for you, I do know what probably causes this issue. Have a look here: [JPEG Image Orientation and EXIF](https://jdhao.github.io/2019/07/31/image_rotation_exif_info/). I think that `dropzone.js` might be [ignoring the EXIF information when resizing the image](https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+EXIF). I hope this can help you find an answer.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware , thanks a lot. I tried with https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/dropzone-exif-fix and it works fine but I'll do more tests to be sure it's fine